# Is it possible to post a note to Facebook with images

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to post a note to Facebook with images?

Comment: Why the unaccept of my answer?

Comment: Hi, DMCS, actually, it is possible to include a photo link in the "message" param when post note to facebook. It is html format string. Though "message" only can cantain certain tag like li,br ... , it can contain img tag also. I have done the task by post a html message, which contains external url link to photos. However thank you all the same.

Comment: Facebook is always changing their API.  So maybe now they've overcome the deficiency that I wrote about on March 1st, 2012.  It's been many months.  Please add your own answer to the correct response and mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the image tag in your description HTML. You can add as many images as you want and position them how you want. You need to do it with HTML. CSS will not work in description.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot post a `note` with images.  There is no image connection on the `note` graph object. `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/note/`
As you can see here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ in the `notes` section.

> **Create**
>
> You can create a note on behalf of the user by issuing an HTTP POST
> request to PROFILE_ID/notes with the publish_stream permissions and
> the following parameters.
>
> Parameter     Description     Type    Required
>
> *subject*     *The subject of the Note*   *string*    *yes*
>
> *message*     *Note content*  *string*    *yes*
>
> If the create is successful, you get the following return.
>
> Name  Description     Type
>
> *id*  *The new note ID*   *string*